# videojs with jquery mobile transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile to slide transition to a page like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage(video_page.html, {transition: "slide", reverse: false} );
```

The page I am transitioning to contains a video element displayed using videojs, like this:

```
<video id="vidWindow0" class="video-js vjs-default-skin ref-linked" 
controls preload="auto" data-model-renderer="video" 
data-model-play="true" ></video>
```

The `<video>` element doesn't contain any src since I dynamically add it in a function that is bound to the `"pagebeforechange"` event. The problem I am having is that when transitioning to this page, I can briefly see the `<video>` element appear just before the old page starts sliding away. It tends to overlap on the old page, making the transition look very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.ui-page {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```